# Multiple ggplots causing legend problems

Tags: r, ggplot2

I currently have the code included below to create this:
[image]
This is more or less how I want it. However, 2 outstanding things I would like the ability to change, but am struggling to sort out myself are: 1) Remove the legend with the title ‘Group’ and have a legend for the thicker black line on the graph with the heading ‘Mean’ (while making sure the line itself remains black) and 2) The ability to change the fill colours of geom_polygons and geom_points that are displayed to custom colour values (without making the legends disappear). Thanks.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape)
library(car)

G1 <- 1:10
G2 <- 11:20
G3 <- 21:30
G4 <- 31:35
G5 <- 36:41

sdata <- read.csv("http://dl.dropbox.com/u/58164604/sdata.csv", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
pdata<-melt(sdata, id.vars="Var")
jdata <-pdata

pdata$group <- recode(pdata$Var, "G1 = 'A'; G2 = 'B'; G3 = 'C'; G4 = 'D'; G5 = 'E'")

VarArea <- data.frame(unique(pdata$Var))
VarFinalArea <-c()
for (g in 1:max(VarArea))
{
VarNum<-pdata[which(pdata$Var==g),1:c(ncol(pdata))]
VarMin <- min(VarNum$value)
VarMax <- max(VarNum$value)
VarMinMax <- cbind(VarMin, VarMax)
VarFinalArea <- rbind(VarFinalArea,VarMinMax)
}
VarFinal <- data.frame(cbind(VarArea,VarFinalArea))
colnames(VarFinal)<-c("Variable", "Min", "Max")
VarFinal$group <- recode(VarFinal$Variable, "G1 = 'A'; G2 = 'B'; G3 = 'C'; G4 = 'D'; G5 = 'E'")

VarArea <- data.frame(unique(jdata$Var))
NumV <- max(VarArea)
VarFinalMin <-c()
for (g in 1:NumV)
{
VarNum<-jdata[which(jdata$Var==g),1:c(ncol(jdata))]
VarN <- g
VarMin <- min(VarNum$value)
VarMinN <- cbind(VarN, VarMin)
VarFinalMin <- rbind(VarFinalMin,VarMinN)
}
VFinalMin <- data.frame(VarFinalMin)
colnames(VFinalMin)<-c("Variable", "Value")
VFinalMin_Max<-max(VFinalMin$Value)

VarFinalMax <-c()
for (g in 1:NumV)
{
VarNum<-jdata[which(jdata$Var==g),1:c(ncol(jdata))]
VarN <- g
VarMax <- max(VarNum$value)
VarMaxN <- cbind(VarN, VarMax)
VarFinalMax <- rbind(VarFinalMax,VarMaxN)
}
VFinalMax <- data.frame(VarFinalMax)
colnames(VFinalMax)<-c("Variable", "Value")
VFinalMax_Min<-min(VFinalMax$Value)

VFinal<-rbind(VFinalMin, VFinalMax)
VFinal$Group <- recode(VFinal$Variable, "G1 = 'A'; G2 = 'B'; G3 = 'C'; G4 = 'D'; G5 = 'E'")

VLarge <- VFinal[which(VFinal$Value >= VFinalMax_Min),]
VLarge <- VLarge[order(-VLarge$Variable, VLarge$Group),]
VSmall <- VFinal[which(VFinal$Value <= VFinalMin_Max),]
VSmall <- VSmall[order(VSmall$Variable, VSmall$Group),]
VFinal <- rbind(VSmall, VLarge)

AMin <-min(jdata$value)
AMax <-max(jdata$value)

AMinValue<-round_any(AMin,1000, f =floor)
AMaxValue<-round_any(AMax,1000, f =ceiling)

ggplot(VFinal, aes(Variable, Value, colour = Group)) + geom_polygon(colour=NA, aes(fill=Group), alpha=0.5) +scale_x_discrete(name="Missing Variable Number", limits=c(1:NumV)) + theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=270, vjust=0.5, hjust=0.0))+ scale_y_continuous(name="Within Cluster Sum of Squares", limits=c(AMinValue, AMaxValue), breaks = seq(AMinValue, AMaxValue, 1000)) + guides(fill=guide_legend(title="Variable Groups"))

last_plot()+geom_line(data=subset(pdata,variable =='Mean'),size=1.5, alpha=0.5, aes(Var, value), colour="black", inherit.aes = FALSE)

last_plot()+geom_line(data=subset(pdata,variable!='Mean'),size=0.5, alpha=0.5, aes(Var, value, shape=variable), colour='black', inherit.aes = FALSE) 

last_plot()+geom_point(data=subset(pdata,variable!='Mean'), aes(Var, value, shape = variable, col=group),alpha=1.0, inherit.aes = FALSE) + labs (shape = "Number of Clusters") + guides(scale_alpha(guide='none'))

last_plot()+ ggtitle("Clusters with Missing Variables") + theme(plot.title = element_text(size = 14, colour = "black", face = "bold"))
```

Comment: 1) is going to be difficult; you can remove the legend with `+ guides(colour = "none")`, but a custom legend with the black line is not part of ggplot2's paradigm. You could instead add a `+ annotate("text", label = "Mean", ...)` directly on the plot, next to the line? For 2) you can use `scale_fill_manual` with your own colours.

Comment: Thanks for the tip about removing the unwanted legend and custom colours. I thought it may be difficult to add a legend for the black line. The closest I have come is this:     `last_plot()+geom_line(data=subset(pdata,variable =='Mean'),size=1.5, alpha=0.5, aes(Var, value, colour="black"), inherit.aes = FALSE)` - by putting colour inside `aes`, but then it disappears when the other layers of the plot are added.

Comment: i didn't notice, but you don't seem to use the size aesthetic. Use that for your lines, and with a manual size legend it should get you there (you may have to pick the breaks carefully).

Comment: To expand upon baptiste's suggestion, you could do something like `aes(Var, value, size = '')` for the mean line and then add the argument `size = guide_legend(title = "Mean", override.aes = list(size = 1.5, colour = "black"))` to your `guides` call.

Comment: To change the colors of your groups, have a look at `?scale_colour_manual`.  E.g., `... + scale_colour_manual("Variable Groups", values = c("A" = "red", "B" = "blue", "C" = "purple", "D" = "salmon", "E" = "orange"))`

Comment: Or consider using `linetype` instead of size in the first trick since you're setting a manual size outside of `aes`.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to baptiste and user1935457 for helping me create this:

[image]

This is how it was done:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape)
library(car)

G1 <- 1:10
G2 <- 11:20
G3 <- 21:30
G4 <- 31:35
G5 <- 36:41

sdata <- read.csv("http://dl.dropbox.com/u/58164604/sdata.csv", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
pdata<-melt(sdata, id.vars="Var")
jdata <-pdata

pdata$group <- recode(pdata$Var, "G1 = 'A'; G2 = 'B'; G3 = 'C'; G4 = 'D'; G5 = 'E'")

VarArea <- data.frame(unique(pdata$Var))
VarFinalArea <-c()
for (g in 1:max(VarArea))
{
VarNum<-pdata[which(pdata$Var==g),1:c(ncol(pdata))]
VarMin <- min(VarNum$value)
VarMax <- max(VarNum$value)
VarMinMax <- cbind(VarMin, VarMax)
VarFinalArea <- rbind(VarFinalArea,VarMinMax)
}
VarFinal <- data.frame(cbind(VarArea,VarFinalArea))
colnames(VarFinal)<-c("Variable", "Min", "Max")
VarFinal$group <- recode(VarFinal$Variable, "G1 = 'A'; G2 = 'B'; G3 = 'C'; G4 = 'D'; G5 = 'E'")

VarArea <- data.frame(unique(jdata$Var))
NumV <- max(VarArea)
VarFinalMin <-c()
for (g in 1:NumV)
{
VarNum<-jdata[which(jdata$Var==g),1:c(ncol(jdata))]
VarN <- g
VarMin <- min(VarNum$value)
VarMinN <- cbind(VarN, VarMin)
VarFinalMin <- rbind(VarFinalMin,VarMinN)
}
VFinalMin <- data.frame(VarFinalMin)
colnames(VFinalMin)<-c("Variable", "Value")
VFinalMin_Max<-max(VFinalMin$Value)

VarFinalMax <-c()
for (g in 1:NumV)
{
VarNum<-jdata[which(jdata$Var==g),1:c(ncol(jdata))]
VarN <- g
VarMax <- max(VarNum$value)
VarMaxN <- cbind(VarN, VarMax)
VarFinalMax <- rbind(VarFinalMax,VarMaxN)
}
VFinalMax <- data.frame(VarFinalMax)
colnames(VFinalMax)<-c("Variable", "Value")
VFinalMax_Min<-min(VFinalMax$Value)

VFinal<-rbind(VFinalMin, VFinalMax)
VFinal$Group <- recode(VFinal$Variable, "G1 = 'A'; G2 = 'B'; G3 = 'C'; G4 = 'D'; G5 = 'E'")

VLarge <- VFinal[which(VFinal$Value >= VFinalMax_Min),]
VLarge <- VLarge[order(-VLarge$Variable, VLarge$Group),]
VSmall <- VFinal[which(VFinal$Value <= VFinalMin_Max),]
VSmall <- VSmall[order(VSmall$Variable, VSmall$Group),]
VFinal <- rbind(VSmall, VLarge)

AMin <-min(jdata$value)
AMax <-max(jdata$value)

AMinValue<-round_any(AMin,1000, f =floor)
AMaxValue<-round_any(AMax,1000, f =ceiling)

ggplot(VFinal, aes(Variable, Value, colour = Group)) + geom_polygon(colour=NA, aes(fill=Group), alpha=0.5) +scale_x_discrete(name="Missing Variable Number", limits=c(1:NumV)) + theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=270, vjust=0.5, hjust=0.0))+ scale_y_continuous(name="Within Cluster Sum of Squares", limits=c(AMinValue, AMaxValue), breaks = seq(AMinValue, AMaxValue, 1000)) + guides(fill=guide_legend(title="Variable Groups"))+ scale_fill_manual("Variable Groups", values = c("A" = "red", "B" = "blue", "C" = "purple", "D" = "salmon", "E" = "orange"))

last_plot()+geom_line(data=subset(pdata,variable =='Mean'), alpha=0.5, aes(Var, value, size= ''), colour="black", inherit.aes = FALSE)+ guides (size = guide_legend(title = "Mean", override.aes = list(size = 1.5, colour = "black")))

last_plot()+geom_line(data=subset(pdata,variable!='Mean'),size=0.5, alpha=0.5, aes(Var, value, shape=variable), colour='black', inherit.aes = FALSE) 

last_plot()+geom_point(data=subset(pdata,variable!='Mean'), aes(Var, value, shape = variable, col=group),alpha=1.0, inherit.aes = FALSE) + labs (shape = "Number of Clusters") + guides(scale_alpha(guide='none')) + guides(colour = "none") + scale_colour_manual("Variable Groups", values = c("A" = "red", "B" = "blue", "C" = "purple", "D" = "salmon", "E" = "orange"))

last_plot()+ ggtitle("Clusters with Missing Variables") + theme(plot.title = element_text(size = 14, colour = "black", face = "bold"))
```